# PHP bind_param error

Tags: php, mysqli

When I start my script this Error appears:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Jil/login_skript.php on line 16

Here is the script:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, vorname, nachname, username, email, passwort, profilBild, geschlecht, alter, wohnort, ueberSich FROM benutzer WHERE username LIKE '?' LIMIT 1;";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that 'alter' is a MySQL keyword.  Enclose all your field names (or at least just 'alter') in backticks to fix this.

Also, don't put quotes around the '?'s in a prepared statement.  They will be added for you.

```
$sql = "SELECT `ID`, `vorname`, `nachname`, `username`, `email`, `passwort`, `profilBild`, `geschlecht`, `alter`, `wohnort`, `ueberSich` FROM `benutzer` WHERE `username` LIKE ? LIMIT 1;";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because your select statement is invalid and the prepare returns NULL. You don't need the `'` around the `?`. There may be other errors as well that you can see by calling `$db->error`

Comment: add this after the prepare statement: